# A gas absorbs heat $Q$ isobarically

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I encountered a question asking "When gas absorbs heat $Q$ isobarically, what will be its work done, change in internal energy and temperature?" The work done is obviously positive, but I can't figure out how the internal energy and temperature would vary. Could someone pls explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you heat a gas isobarically, part of the heat (energy) will make the gas expand (work done) and the other part of the heat makes makes gas temperature (internal energy) increase.

This can be shown in different ways, I explain them in two simple ways:

For an ideal gas model: $PV=nRT$ for isobaric process $P=constant$, so we can rearrange it to $V=\frac{nR}{P} T$, we can define $\frac{nR}{P}=k$, where $k$ is constant, so $V=k\ T$. From this, it can be seen that by heating a gas it expands and also its temperature increases.

2nd approach: Second law (conservation of energy) for the control mass system is as below:

$Q-W=\Delta U$, by substituting $W$ for isobaric process $W=P \Delta V$,  we get $Q=\Delta h$, where $h$ is Enthalpy. This equation shows by adding heat to the system its enthalpy (thus internal energy) increases.

We can go further for ideal gas by substituting $\Delta h=C_p \Delta T$ into previous equation, so we have $Q=C_p \Delta T$, which shows by heating a gas, its temperature rises.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

For a closed system (no mass transfer) the internal energy will vary according to the first law, or

$$\Delta U=Q-W\tag{1}$$

Where $Q$ is positive if the heat is absorbed by the system and $W$ is positive if work is done by the system. For an isobaric process,

$$W=P_{ext}\Delta V\tag{2}$$.

The variation in temperature will depend on the type of system. For an ideal gas, any process,

$$\Delta U=nC_{v}\Delta T\tag{3}$$

Substituting (2) and (3) into (1) for an ideal gas

$$nC_{v}\Delta T=Q-P_{ext}\Delta V\tag{4}$$

Hope this helps.